# gtk+ without msys2 mingw

Tags: gtk, libpng

On Windows, trying something with gtk+. I have downloaded Msys2, along with gtk+3.0.

Successfully compiled all the gtk+3.0 examples in the msys2 mingw-w64 terminal.

Now I want to move a bit further to try work without the msys environment.

I opened up cmd and navigated to where the example executables are compiled. Then I fired them up by typing "example.exe".

`libgio-2.0-0.dll missing`, not surprised. I go back to check the PATH environment of the msys environment, `PATH=/mingw64/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:..blablabla`

So in the cmd environment I did `set PATH=%PATH%;pathto/mingw64/bin;` and run example.exe again.

This time it gave a very strange error `cannot find entrypoint inflateValidate (in dll libpng16-16.dll)`

So I checked, indeed there was no inflateValidate function in the dll. it seemed to me that something thought the function is in the dll and tried to call it but because it doesn't exist so it failed. What I don't understand is that why did it not fail in the msys environment but failed in the windows environment. And does that bring any impact to me if I am going to ship any gtk application? I thought simply distributing the relevant dll would be enough.

I have tried instead of adding the `mingw64/bin` path to the PATH variable, but copying the required dll the the execute location 1 by 1, but at the end it still gave the same error.

I have also tried to search for other libpng*.dll in my computer, none of them contained the `inflateValidate` function.

If anyone know whats going on please shed some light to the question.

Comment: OK, seemed order of PATH variables matter, I changed PATH to `set PATH=pathto/mingw64/bin;%PATH%`, then it worked. Turns out inflateValidate is a zlib function and I did not copy the zlib dll because the dll missing error did not popup. perhaps by putting the mingw64/bin first it ensures that the same compiler zlib and libpng is used. I shall just keep the question and comment here for future reference.

Comment: I had this very same error, but it was caused by an outdated zlib.dll in MSYS2.  I entered `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib` in MSYS2's shell to update it and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I might be very late to the party but I ran into the same issue yesterday (missing the inflateValidate symbol) and after checking the contents of the zlib1.dll file could ascertain that the function is just not there.

I downloaded another version (specifically this one https://sourceforge.net/projects/uqm-mods/files/latest/download, though I am in no way affiliated to this project) and saw that the inflateValidate symbol was indeed declared, so I suppose that the zlib bundled with your files is not up to date with the libpng requirements.

This solved my problem. I hope it solves yours too.